Why does my code show empty values when I try to insert it?
I am using Maatwebsite to import an Excel file and save data in my database, the importing process works fine, when I dd($row) I can see the data I have in my file, but for some reasons I ignore when I insert the row it show empty values for all the field.
This is the Excel I try to import

This is the code of my controller
public function saveStudentFromExcel(Request $request)
    {
        try {
        // Validate the uploaded file
        $request->validate([
            'excel' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls',
        ]);

        // Get the uploaded file
        $file = $request->file('excel');

        // Process the Excel file
        Excel::import(new ImportStudent, $file);
        session()->flash('success','Élèves enregistrés avec succès.');
        return redirect('student');
        }catch (Throwable $e)
        {
            dd($e->getMessage());
            session()->flash('error', 'Une erreur est survenue durant l\'opération, veuillez essayer à nouveau');
            return redirect('student');
        }

    }

And this is the import student class
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\helpers;
use App\Models\Student;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\{Importable, ToCollection};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;


class ImportStudent implements ToCollection
{
    use Importable;

    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        $management=(new helpers())->data()[1];
        $school_year=(new helpers())->data()[9];
        foreach ($collection as $row)
        {
            dd($row);
            $password=$this->generatePassword(8);
            $student=new Student();
            $student->first_name=ucwords($row[1]);
            $student->last_name=strtoupper($row[0]);
            $student->id_school_year=$school_year;
            $student->photo='avatar.jpg';
            $student->parent_first_name=ucwords($row[6]);
            $student->parent_last_name=strtoupper($row[5]);
            $student->date_of_birth=Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[2]);
            $student->sexe=$row[4];
            $student->city='Aucun';
            $student->id_class_room=$row[8];
            $student->email=strtolower($row[0]).strtolower($row[1]).'thesunht.com';
            $student->matricule=$row[3];
            $student->documents=$row[7];
            $student->save();
                DB::table('users')->insert([
                    'name'=>strtoupper($row[0]).' '.ucwords($row[1]),
                    'role'=>'student',
                    'email'=> strtolower($row[0]).strtolower($row[1]).'thesunht.com',
                    'campus'=>$management->campus,
                    'status'=>'active',
                    'password'=>Hash::make($password)
                ]);
                DB::table('data')->insert([
                    'email'=>strtolower($row[0]).strtolower($row[1]).'thesunht.com',
                    'password'=>$password,
                    'campus'=>$management->campus
                ]);
    }
        }

    public function generatePassword($length):string {
        $pattern = '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';
        return substr(str_shuffle($pattern), 0, $length);
    }
}


When I print the value of a row I can see this

However, when I try to insert data I can see this
. This is my first time importing a file, I don't know if I'm missing something. All the fields are fillable in my Model. Can anyone help me please?
